# Error en carga de campos VB6

Tags: botón, vb, vb6, click

Tengo el siguiente problema, tengo un botón que añade campos en un formulario en VB6. 
La idea es que solo se puedan añadir hasta 3 veces, una vez que llega al tercero (es decir cuando se hace el tercer click en el botón) este se tiene que inhabilitar. Pero, me sale este error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

También como ven en el GIF, recién al cuarto click se inhabilita el botón:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Les adjunto el código:

```
Option Explicit
Private oldPos As Integer

Dim indice As Integer
Dim indicee As Integer
Dim contador As Integer 'para la cantidad de cuadros

Private Sub btnAñadir_Click()
   'indice = indice + 1
   indicee = indicee + 0

   'If contador = 3 Then
   If indice = 3 Then
   'indice = 0
   Me.btnAñadir.Enabled = False
   Else
   indice = indice + 1
   'Me.btnAñadir.Enabled = True
   'contador = contador + 1
   End If

   Picture1.Visible = True

   Load uc1(indice)
   Set uc1(indice).Container = Picture1  'place the control inside the PictureBox
   uc1(indice).Visible = True
   uc1(indice).Top = IIf(indice = 1, 0, uc1(indice - 1).Top + uc1(indice - 1).Height + 20)

   Load lblTipo(indice)
   Set lblTipo(indice).Container = uc1(indice)
   lblTipo(indice).Visible = True
   lblTipo(indice).Top = lblTipo(indice - 1).Top
   'cmbAddTipo
   Load cmbAddTipo(indice)
   Set cmbAddTipo(indice).Container = uc1(indice)
   cmbAddTipo(indice).Visible = True
   cmbAddTipo(indice).Top = cmbAddTipo(indice - 1).Top

   'lblAddPrefijo
   Load lblAddPrefijo(indice)
   Set lblAddPrefijo(indice).Container = uc1(indice)
   lblAddPrefijo(indice).Visible = True
   lblAddPrefijo(indice).Top = lblAddPrefijo(indice - 1).Top
   'txtAddPrefijo
   Load txtAddPrefijo(indice)
   Set txtAddPrefijo(indice).Container = uc1(indice)
   txtAddPrefijo(indice).Visible = True
   txtAddPrefijo(indice).Top = txtAddPrefijo(indice - 1).Top

   'lblAddNum
   Load lblAddNum(indice)
   Set lblAddNum(indice).Container = uc1(indice)
   lblAddNum(indice).Visible = True
   lblAddNum(indice).Top = lblAddNum(indice - 1).Top
   'txtAddNumero
   Load txtAddNumero(indice)
   Set txtAddNumero(indice).Container = uc1(indice)
   txtAddNumero(indice).Visible = True
   txtAddNumero(indice).Top = txtAddNumero(indice - 1).Top

   'checkAddPrincipal
   Load chkAddPrincipal(indice)
   Set chkAddPrincipal(indice).Container = uc1(indice)
   chkAddPrincipal(indice).Visible = True
   chkAddPrincipal(indice).Top = chkAddPrincipal(indice - 1).Top

   'chkAddActual
   Load chkAddActual(indice)
   Set chkAddActual(indice).Container = uc1(indice)
   chkAddActual(indice).Visible = True
   chkAddActual(indice).Top = chkAddActual(indice - 1).Top

   'lblAddVin
   Load lblAddVin(indice)
   Set lblAddVin(indice).Container = uc1(indice)
   lblAddVin(indice).Visible = True
   lblAddVin(indice).Top = lblAddVin(indice - 1).Top
   'cmbAddVinculo
   Load cmbAddVinculo(indice)
   Set cmbAddVinculo(indice).Container = uc1(indice)
   cmbAddVinculo(indice).Visible = True
   cmbAddVinculo(indice).Top = cmbAddVinculo(indice - 1).Top


End Sub
Private Sub Form_Load()

   Dim theDate As Date
   theDate = Format(Now(), "short date")
   TextBox1.Text = theDate

   scrollAdd.Min = 0
   scrollAdd.Max = 3000
   scrollAdd.SmallChange = Screen.TwipsPerPixelX * 10
   scrollAdd.LargeChange = scrollAdd.SmallChange
End Sub

Private Sub scrollAdd_Change()
   ScrollControls
End Sub

Private Sub scrollAdd_Scroll()
   ScrollControls
End Sub

Private Sub ScrollControls()
   Dim c As Control

   For Each c In Me.Controls
      If c.Container.Name = "Picture1" And Not TypeOf c Is VScrollBar Then
         c.Top = c.Top + (oldPos - scrollAdd.Value)
      End If
   Next

   oldPos = scrollAdd.Value
End Sub
```

Esto sucede si pongo `If indice = 2`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Dónde pones `If indice = 3 Then` debe ser `If indice = 2 Then`. Respecto del error, deberías especificar en que línea del código aparece.

Comment: @RogerTorné Puse el `If indice = 2` pero solo se añaden 2 veces los campos. Yo necesito que se añadan 3 veces y que al presionar esa tercera vez se inhabilite ese botón. El error surge al momento de presionar el botón por última vez

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que al hacer esto:

```
Dim indice As Integer
```

El valor inicial de indice es 0.

Por lo tanto, para que ocurra esto:

```
If indice = 3 Then
    'indice = 0
    Me.btnAñadir.Enabled = False
```

Hay que apretar 4 veces..

dale un valor a indice que sea = 1 o hace que en ese if indice sea igual a 2

---

Otro problema es el siguiente:

cuando haces

```
    If indice = 3 Then
        Me.btnAñadir.Enabled = False
    Else
        indice = indice + 1
    End If

   Picture1.Visible = True

   Load uc1(indice)
```

cuando indice es 3, apagas el boton como queres, pero no sumas indice, y como la funcion sigue, entonces tratas de hacer load de un control que ya existe.

Ese if deberia ir al final de la funcion y asi se solucionaria tu problema. Y la suma a indice la deberia hacer siempre

Comment: Si pongo indice = 2, solo se añaden dos veces y yo necesito que se añadan 3 veces los campos.

Comment: puse o.. si pones indice 2, se agrega 3 veces porque necesitas apretar 3 veces para que llegue de 0 a 2... @FranqoBalsamo

Comment: Edité el post para que se entienda lo que trato de decir pero digo mal

Comment: Si pongo el `If`al final de la función sale el error apenas presiono el botón una vez

Comment: @FranqoBalsamo pero no todo el if, solo la parte que apaga el boton. Indice lo tenes que sumar siempre.. se entendio eso?

Comment: Genio, no me había dado cuenta de eso. Muchas gracias, me ha servido de maravilla.

Answer (score 1):

En tienes que poner un punto de salida cuando llegas a 3 porque y  inicializalo con la propiedad GetUpperBound(0) que te devuelve cuantos has cargado. 
' Length o Upperbound te devuelve el tamaño de array
         Indice= uc1.GetUpperbound(0)

```
     If uc1.GetUpperbound(0) >= 3 then
         BtnAñadir.Enabled = false
          Exit sub
   Else
```

......
     Te sale el error porque
 Estas cargando nuevamente el indice. El uc1 es un array supongo.